# Does the physical distance from electrolyc capacitor to inductor matter?

Tags: capacitor, noise, inductor, passive-networks, interference

I am designing simple LC circuit (L=470uH, C=1000uF) for 12V / 12A (1 Ohm load):

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I did do some soldering already (without too much or noob thinking). The capacitor and inductor are almost touching each other (just 2-3mm space between their bodies).

Since both: inductance and capacity are quite big, I was wondering if this may cause some interference between them (inductor's magnetic fields etc...)?

Comment: *if this may cause some interference between them* No, that's not a problem. Inductors work with a **magnetic** field. Capacitors with an **electric** field. This should not cause any interference problems. However in fast switching buck (not bulk !) converters, what **is** crtitical is the connections between: switching transistor, flyback diode, inductor and capacitor. You should make these connections as short as possible. Look for example at the datasheet of the LM2596, there's an example for a board layout. Note how these components are placed such that the loops are as small as possible.

Comment: No schematic, no help.

Comment: Here you have it - added to the question

Answer (score 3):

You should try to minimize the loop area of the circuit in both modes of conduction. In particular, the part of the loop that changes between modes.

[image]

When the transistor is on, current flows from the capacitor I drew, through L1 and C1 and the transistor (green loop).

When the transistor turns off, current flows through D1, L1 and C1 (pink loop).

Minimize the **area** of both of those loops to minimize the EMI the circuit produces. In practice that usually means putting them as close together as possible, but visualizing the loops helps.

Comment: Don't mind me asking: what is EMI?

Comment: You should wait longer before accepting an answer. That will help increase the kwality of the answers. EMI is electromagnetic interference. If your circuit makes too much EMI it can interfere with other devices and it can reduce the efficiency.

Comment: "What is EMI?" Put an AM radio near this thing and you'll find out!

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - I revoked approval as sugested ;-)